# Neo4j rebuilding database

Tags: neo4j

We would like to import every day or so, tens of millions of nodes with relationships.
neo4j-admin import seems to be very slow (we removed all constrains and indexes before).

1. What is the best practice to load a huge amount of data into neo?
2. We would like every other day, when we import, to import it into a different database and SWITCH between the current database and the newly built database. (similar to alias index in elastic search).
   How can this be done?

Thank you

Comment: You find that the `neo4j-admin import` is slow ? The one with CSV files with a predefined format,  that is able to initiate a database ?

Comment: @logisima - I am trying to import to existing dB

Comment: So what is this `neo4j-admin import seems to be very slow (we removed all constrains and indexes before).` ? What have you already test ? Do you have an example of data you want to import ? For 2), can you have a downtime (time of a restart) ?

Comment: both import & LOAD CSV seems to be very slow. But we cannot except downtime

Comment: it's NOT normal that the import tool is slow ... so what do you mean by slow ?. Can you give the result of your import with this method ?

Comment: Slow means that a 100MB file with 5m of records haven't finished within 30minuets